# Heat change of mixing substances in different phases

Tags: thermodynamics

> 10 g of water at 70C is mixed with 5g of water at 30C Find temperature of mixture in equilibrium

I solve this problem by first converting the water at 70C to  40C and using the excess energy to figure out how much the combined water should rise up.

---

However my book had another approach to it as follows:

$$ Q_{\text{heat given by steam}} = Q_{\text{heat taken by water}}$$

Then,

$$ m_1 c_1 | \Delta t_1 | =  m_2 c_2 | \Delta t_2|$$

Now what exactly is the idea behind modulus of the temperature changes?

Comment: The two methods are completely equivalent mathematically, and also equivalent to saying that the change in internal energy $\Delta U$ of the combined system is zero (since no net heat is transferred to, nor work done by the combined system).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The temperature change for the cold body is positive while that for the hot body is negative.
You could have also done this as - The process involves heat exchange between the participating bodies only and no heat is lost  to the surrounding. So, $$m_1s_1(T-T_1) +m_2s_2(T-T_2) = 0$$
Upon rearranging you will arrive at the given result.

Comment: If I understood correctly, they did this just take care of the signs involved (heat flow only from hot to cold)?

Comment: Yes. When heat is lost $∆T$ will be negative , so you have to take care of signs.

Answer (score 1):

The heat energy gained or lost by a mass $m$ when it changes temperature by an amount $\Delta T$ is proportional to $m$ and to $\Delta T$. Since the two quantities involved here are both water, we can expect the constant of proportionality to be the same (in your notation, we can assume that $c_1=c_2$). So if the $10$ g of water becomes colder by $\Delta_1 T$ and the $5$ g of water becomes warmer by $\Delta_2 T$ then conservation of energy tells us that

$10 \Delta_1 T = 5 \Delta_2 T$

But both parts must end up at the same temperature, so

$\Delta_1 T + \Delta_2 T = 70 - 30 = 40$

I'll let you take it from there.

If you were mixing two different substances then their specific heat capacities would not be the same ($c_1 \ne c_2$) and the problem would become more difficult.